# How does one send data from a dictionary over an mqtt broker

Tags: python, dictionary, mosquitto

Basically I have two raspberry pi's and I want one to publish data obtained from a dictionary in a python file and the the other to subscribe to this dictionary data.  Apologies if this is a very bland question but I can't find any info on the internet regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you read a basic MQTT tutorial if you have not done that already. That will help you decide what your topics and data should be like.

To get you started, here is an example of how you could publish and subscribe for your use case.
The publisher could iterate through the keys in the dictionary and publish data to topic "keys/$key_name" with the message being the value for that key in the dictionary.

The subscriber could subscribe to topic "keys/#". This way the subscriber will get all the keys and the corresponding data and reconstruct the dictionary.

There are many more ways you could publish data depending on the nature of data in your dictionary.

Comment: I feel I will only need one topic and I should be able to iterate the dictionary but I am not sure how to iterate in the context of publishing what I have iterated to the broker.  I've tried converting the dictionary to a json and the broker is receiving it but how does a subscriber break down the json in order to read the data?

Comment: Seems like your question is about how to reconstruct dictionary from json and not related to mqtt and pub-sub ? If yes, this might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496513/json-to-dictionary-in-javascript

If not, can you please elaborate what your question is ?

Comment: My dictionary is formatted as follows, the key is a datetime and the value is a float.  But mqtt specifies the payload can only be a string, byte array, int, float or None.  So my dictionary is incompatible basically and I'm probably limited to what I can do if my keys are datetime objects.  Would you recommend I alter my dictionary and convert the keys to a compatible datatype before publishing it?

Comment: If you convert each entry in the dictionary to a json (something like {"timestamp: "", value:""}, then this is a string that can be published to any topic. You could publish each entry in the dictionary separately to the same topic or you could concatenate all entries and send a large string. Would depend on how large your dictionary is and how is the subscriber handling the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a dictionary directly from a python script on Host A to a python script on Host B there is a way.

1. Convert your dictionary into a string.
2. Send the string as a payload from Host A to the broker.
3. Subscribe to the broker with Host B and receive the payload.
4. Evaluate the string with ast.literal_eval() which will convert it back into a dictionary.

If that explanation is unclear I could post some example code.

I would probably use JSON or multiple topics instead but the above procedure will work.